# How to generate a random code for each session using php for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, xcode, shortcode, contact-form-7

I am using Contact form 7 in Wordpress , where I want to add a field of uneditable random code . I am using the following code and using the Dynamic hidden field to display it. But is there any way that I can show this code on any page (where I want) after submitting this form? e.g, Your submitted code was : 32372377

```
function rzh_cf7_GenNomor() {
  $panjang = 10; // Length number generated
  $karakter = "0123456789"; // random character
  for ($p = 0; $p < $panjang; $p++) {
    $string .= $karakter[mt_rand(0,strlen($karakter)-1)];

  }
  return $string;
}
add_shortcode('RZH_CF7_GEN_NOMOR', 'rzh_cf7_GenNomor');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add data to the global $_SESSION variable that will be accessible at any point within the application during a user session by accessing the $_SESSION variable. The variable is an array; below is an example of adding data to the session array.

```
$foo = add_shortcode('RZH_CF7_GEN_NOMOR', 'rzh_cf7_GenNomor');
$_SESSION[‘foo’] = $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the following function in your custom shortcode in function.php

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
   return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}
```